How did talmidei chachamim do teshuva overnight
I heard the Gemara that says that if you see a Talmid chacham sin at night, you can assume that by morning he did teshuva
But an teshuva really be done overnight? Doesn’t it take time to do (for example, Rambam saying you must be in the same position as you were when you first sinned to do teshuva)? Regret isn’t the only aspect of teshuva. So how can this talmid do teshuva overnight?

The Rambam you refer to is describing תשובה גמורה. In the very next halacha (2:2) he gives the basic requirements for teshuvah, which, for a single sin, can plausibly be accomplished in 10 minutes. (Obviously only if one is genuinely sincere.)

This question is similar to: How is Teshuva right before death possible?, i.e. I think that the answers there will also directly answer your question here (and @joelk answered the Rambam). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RabbiKaii Looks like that has the answer but would you mind summarizing what was said there all the answers were a bit confusing

@CuriousYid could you let me know something specific you find confusing? The simple fact is that it's a very standard idea in Torah that a person can do Teshuva - truly regret something to the point of changing into a person who would never do it again - in an instant. It's not common, and for most cases Teshuva is hard and takes time, but it certainly can happen, so therefore one should don lechaf zechus that a talmid chacham did teshuva overnight (which is a weaker case anyway). Being in the same scenario is mainly "proof" that the Teshuva happened, but internally, Teshuva doesn't need...

...that, so we can assume that the talmid chacham has changed and won't do it again - we don't need proof for that.

@RabbiKaii ok I more or less get that thank you
